# Insert values inside object with Promise in node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to send values inside a object but the problem that I have only the last values

This is my script :

```
async function allTemp() {
const element = {};

const listTopic = require("../scripts/findTopic.js");

/*Output: Map {
  0 => '{home/sensors/temp/kitchen}',
  1 => '{home/sensors/temp/bathroom}',
  2 => '{home/sensors/temp/room}' }*/

var options = {
    ***
};

var client = mqtt.connect('***', options);

// Wait for connection with a Promise
await new Promise(resolve => client.on('connect', resolve));

// subscribe to a topic
for (let [key, value] of listTopic.allTopics()) {
    const topicSelected = value;
    var newTopic = topicSelected.substring(1, topicSelected.length - 1);
    client.subscribe(newTopic, { qos: 0 });

    // Wait for message event
    const { topic, message } = await new Promise(resolve => client.once("message", (topic, message) => resolve({ topic, message })));
    element["topic"] = topic;
    element["value"] = message.toString();
    element["timestamp"] = new Date()
 }
 console.log(element);
 return mapResultTemp;
}

allTemp();
module.exports = { allTemp };
```

The problem is that retrieve only the last values and want all values inside my object

Actuual result:

```
{ topic: 'home/sensors/temp/room',
  value: '21',
  timestamp: 2021-06-24T08:07:49.272Z }
```

Expected result :

```
[{ topic: 'home/sensors/temp/kitchen',
  value: '24',
  timestamp: 2021-06-24T08:07:49.272Z },
 { topic: 'home/sensors/temp/bathroom',
  value: '22',
  timestamp: 2021-06-24T08:07:49.272Z },
 { topic: 'home/sensors/temp/room',
  value: '21',
  timestamp: 2021-06-24T08:07:49.272Z }]
```

Comment: I don't believe promises will help you here.  A promise is a representation of a single future value, not a stream of values.

Comment: I think you are emulating [Observables](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable). Probably what you actually need.

Comment: Where does `mapResultTemp` come from? You're returning it but it's undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding the `element` variable multiple times. It should have been an array from the start.

```js
async function allTemp() {
const elements = [];

// ...

// subscribe to a topic
for (let [key, value] of listTopic.allTopics()) {
    // ...

    const { topic, message } = await new Promise(resolve => client.once("message", (topic, message) => resolve({ topic, message })));
    const element = {
      topic,
      value: message.toString(),
      timestamp: new Date(),
    };
    elements.push(element);

 }
 console.log(elements);
 return elements;
}

allTemp();
module.exports = { allTemp };
```

Also, you can parallelize the process by calling all promises at the same time

```js
async function allTemp() {
const listTopic = require("../scripts/findTopic.js");

/*Output: Map {
  0 => '{home/sensors/temp/kitchen}',
  1 => '{home/sensors/temp/bathroom}',
  2 => '{home/sensors/temp/room}' }*/

var options = {
    ***
};

var client = mqtt.connect('***', options);

// Wait for connection with a Promise
await new Promise(resolve => client.on('connect', resolve));

const elements = await Promise.all(listTopic.allTopics().map(async ([key, topicSelected]) => {
  const newTopic = topicSelected.substring(1, topicSelected.length - 1);
  client.subscribe(newTopic, { qos: 0 });

  // Wait for message event
  const { topic, message } = await new Promise(resolve => client.once("message", (topic, message) => resolve({ topic, message })));

  return {
    topic,
    value: message.toString(),
    timestamp: new Date(),
  };
});

console.log(elements);

return elements;
}

allTemp();
module.exports = { allTemp };
```

Comment: Should be `elements` I suppose, I copied it from the original...

Comment: Thanks for your help, just for the second script, when you waiting the message event, it says me : "await is only valid in async function" but I already using async no ?

Comment: Actually no, the `map` needs to be async too: `.map(async ([key, topicSelected]) => {`, forgot about it. Async is not propagated down to every function within the body of an async function. It must be re-declared every time

Answer (score 1):

You are not pushing the element in the mapResultTemp array.
Add mapResultTemp.push(element).